# How to test SQL Server stored procedure with external database reference?

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I've inherited a system with the following in a stored procedure.

```
SELECT blah, bleah FROM ThirdPartyDB.dbo.SomeView
```

`ThirdPartyDB` is a client interface DB which we don't have access to other than the a fore mentioned view. All this works fine in production, but currently I can't test it because I don't have a `ThirdPartyDB` on the test server.

Obviously I'd like to address this, but I'm wondering what is the best way to go about this?

Is just creating a new DB on the test server with a table named `SomeView`, which seems the simplest approach the best way, or is there a better way I'm not aware of?